# Add Textfield to ListView and multiply the value of that textfield by the a price of that item

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, statefulwidget

I have a shopping app, Using Provider I am able to create a list of Cart items. Based on the price and the quantity from each item, a grand total is calculated. I want the user to enter their own quantity.

Here is my CartScreen

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text("Items Purchased"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Total',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Chip(
                    label: Text(
                      'GHC ${cart.totalAmount}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(cart);
                      // Provider.of<Orders>(context).addOrder(
                      //     cart.items.values.toList(), cart.totalAmount);
                      // cart.clear();
                    },
                    child: Text("CONFIRM"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cart.itemCount,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CartItemWidget(
                  cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                  cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
                  cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,


                  TextField(
                    controller: _controllers[i],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      final x = double.tryParse(value);
                      setState(() {
                        itemTotal = x ?? 0;
                        itemTotal = cart.items.values.toList()[i].price * x;
                        print(itemTotal);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                  cart.items.values.toList()[i].title,
                  cart.items.values.toList()[i].image),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I think the calculation should be at the `CartItemWidget` instead.

```
class CartItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String productId;
  final double price;
  final Widget quantityField;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;
  final String image;

  CartItemWidget(this.id, this.productId, this.price, this.quantityField,
      this.quantity, this.title, this.image);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(id),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      background: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 4),
      ),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).removeItem(productId);
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: FittedBox(child: Image.asset(image)),
              backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
            ),
            title: Text(title),
            subtitle: Text('Total: GHC ${(price * quantity)}'),
            trailing: Container(width: 70.0, child: TextField()),
            // trailing: Text('$quantity X'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a Model class with Provider too.

```
class CartItem with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;
  final String image;

  CartItem(
      {@required this.id,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.quantity,
      @required this.price,
      this.image});
}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items.length;
  }

  double get totalAmount {
    double total = 0.0;
    _items.forEach((key, cartItem) {
      total += cartItem.price * cartItem.quantity;
    });
    return total;
  }

  double get totalForEachItem {
    double total = 0.0;
    _items(key, cartItem) {
      total = cartItem.price * cartItem.quantity;
    }
  }

  void addItems(String productId, double price, String title, String image) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      //change quantity
      _items.remove(productId);
      // clear();
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
            id: DateTime.now().toString(),
            title: title,
            price: price,
            quantity: 1,
            image: image),
      );
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
  void removeItem(String productId) {
    _items.remove(productId);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void getItemTotal(String productId, double price, int quantity) {}

  void clear() {
    _items = {};
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**What I want**
Currently the product details such as name, price and quantity are passed from the products page. I want the user to enter their own quantity and total will automatically update by multiplying the quantity entered for cartItem[i] by the price at cartItem[i] and add the total for each item for the grandtotal.

**What I have done**
I created a list of controllers so i can get the values at each cartitem. I also used the onChange to get the value to multiply the price and set a total with that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a void function (use a setter type function `set` )that sets the quantity of the item. then tie the `onSubmitted` parameter (or however you're receiving the data) of `textField` with the setter function of the provider.

Now the setter function sets the new value for the quantity of the product and rebuilds the rest of the widgets.

I may not be able to correctly drop you the code, but you could get some help with my idea.

Happy to help :)